# determinant of a matrix c++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

My name's Daniele and I'm a `C++` beginner. In this period I'm trying to improve in pointers, recursive functions and dynamic memory allocation.
For this reason I wrote a code for find the determinant of a square matrix.
This code seems to do its job but give me some problems. When I completed the code, the test with a 5x5 matrix the program crashed; then I changed the return value of the function and the DET variable from int to double. Things seemed to get better but when I've done a test with a 5x5 identity the program crashed again and I don't know why.
Another question, I had to correct the last if-else control statement for the call of the recursive function first was

```
if (dyn_dim > 3) 
{
    DET = DET + coeff*funz_det (temp, (dyn_dim-1));
}
else
{
    return (temp[0][0]*temp[1][1]-temp[0][1]*temp[1][0]); 
}
```

I have seen this on web but for my code doesn't works.
Why also if I put the DET variable as an external variable the code does't work?
Last but not least. I call recursively the function in the way you can see, but is it better write the body of the recursive function in the if-else contro statement or is it the same?
I do not want to write this algorithm for the determinant itself, but for skills that involves.
Thank you very much to everyone
(I apologize in advance for my English)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double funz_det (int **a, int dyn_dim) // dyn_dim: the dynamic dimension created for sub-matrix
{
    double DET = 0;
    /*Create dynamically the new sub-matrix*/
    int **temp;
    temp = new int*[dyn_dim-1];
    for(int i=0; i<dyn_dim; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = new int[dyn_dim-1];
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////

    int coeff = 0;
    int BR = 0;
    int BC = 0;
    int row_index = 0;
    int column_index = 0;
    for (BC = 0; BC != dyn_dim; BC++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<dyn_dim; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<dyn_dim; j++)
            {
                if (i==BR && j==BC)
                {
                    coeff = a[i][j];
                    int esp = i+j;
                    coeff = pow(-1,esp)*coeff;
                    row_index--;
                }
                if (i!=BR && j!=BC)
                {
                    temp[row_index][column_index] = a[i][j];                                     
                    column_index++;
                }
            }
            column_index = 0;    
            row_index++;     
        }
        row_index = 0;
        if (dyn_dim > 3) 
        {
            DET = DET + coeff*funz_det (temp, (dyn_dim-1));
        }
        else
        {
            DET = DET + coeff*(temp[0][0]*temp[1][1]-temp[0][1]*temp[1][0]);             
        }
    }
    return DET;
}

int main()
{
    int dimension = 0;

    cout << "Please insert the matrix dimension:  ";
    cin >> dimension;

    cout << endl << endl;

    int **A;
    A = new int*[dimension];
    for(int d=0; d<dimension; d++)
    {
        A[d] = new int[dimension];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<dimension; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<dimension; j++)
        {
            cout << "Please insert the element A[" << i << "][" << j << "] =  ";            
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int display_row=0; display_row<dimension; display_row++)
    {
        for(int display_column=0; display_column<dimension; display_column++)       
        {
            cout << A[display_row][display_column] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    } 

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Determinant Value = " << funz_det(A,dimension)  <<  endl;

    system ("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be asking several questions here. When you say "Crashed" what happened? Did you get an error message? Stack  dump? What line did the crash happen on? What input were you using?

Comment: Although this is a good exercise, do note that determinants are solved computationally using something called LU decomposition. Computing them your way takes too long for large matrices.

Comment: "pointers, recursive functions and dynamic memory allocation". Not a very good choice of topics for a beginner. Recursion us OK but the other two should be "using the standard library to *avoid* raw pointers and dynamic memory allocations".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code crashing is a common aspect in C++, and very often when you are starting. The thing is that you are not deleting your dynamic pointers. See when you create your sub-matrix at the start of the function? Well, you are using 'new' with your pointers, and that of course is correct, but you always should destroy any pointer you create with 'new', using 'delete', before the pointer goes out of the scope. If you don't do it, you will have memory leaks, and at-run-end crashing errors is a normal symptom of forgotten pointers...

Comment: Memory leaks are bad, but in this case they are not the reason of the crash.

Comment: @Alan Espinet thank you very much!! ok so this must be the next step. I'll try to do it as fast as possible! Thanks a lot to all!

Comment: @Alan Espinet I wanted to give a positive feedback to your answer. I apologize if I wrong and not do it correctly! I'm so sorry